# Relation between `DList` and `[]` with Codensity

Tags: list, haskell, category-theory

I've been experimenting with `Codensity` lately which is supposed to relate `DList` with `[]` among other things. Anyway, I've never found code that states this relation. After some experiments I ended up with this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Codensity where

newtype Codensity f a = Codensity
  { runCodensity :: forall b. (a -> f b) -> f b }

type DList a = Codensity [] [a]

nil :: DList a
nil = Codensity ($ [])

infixr 5 `cons`
cons :: a -> DList a -> DList a
cons x (Codensity xs) = Codensity ($ (xs (x:)))

append :: DList a -> DList a -> DList a
append (Codensity xs) ys = Codensity ($ (xs (++ toList ys)))

toList :: DList a -> [a]
toList xs = runCodensity xs id

fromList :: [a] -> DList a
fromList xs = Codensity (\k -> k xs)
```

However, the definition of `DList` feels a bit icky in my example. Is there a different way to state this relation? Is this even the right way to do this?

Comment: A simple test shows that it is not replicating the performance characteristics of real difference lists: while `length . Data.DList.toList $ Data.DList.fromList [1..1000000] \`Data.DList.append\` Data.DList.fromList [1..1000000]` returns instantly, the corresponding `length . Codensity.toList $ Codensity.fromList [1..1000000] \`Codensity.append\` Codensity.fromList [1..1000000]` takes several seconds.

Comment: Good point, I rewrote `fromList` to change to performance characteristics: `fromList xs = Codensity (\k -> k xs)`

Comment: It's not difference lists: `length . toList . foldl' append nil . map (fromList . (:[]))` is O(n^2).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One view could be that `DList` is a way for reordering monoid operations, just as `Codensity` is a way for reordering monad operations.

`[]` is a free monoid on `a`, so let's represent lists using a free writer monad, that is `Free ((,) a)`:

```
module Codensity where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Free
import Control.Monad.Codensity
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)

type DList a = Free ((,) a) ()
```

Now we can define the standard list operations:

```
nil :: DList a
nil = return ()

singleton :: a -> DList a
singleton x = liftF (x, ())

append :: DList a -> DList a -> DList a
append = (>>)

infixr 5 `snoc`
snoc :: DList a -> a -> DList a
snoc xs x = xs >> singleton x

exec :: Free ((,) a) () -> [a]
exec (Free (x, xs)) = x : exec xs
exec (Pure _) = []

fromList :: [a] -> DList a
fromList = mapM_ singleton

toList :: DList a -> [a]
toList = exec
```

This representation has the same drawbacks as list when it comes to `snoc`. We can verify that

```
last . toList . foldl snoc nil $ [1..10000]
```

takes a significant (quadratic) amount of time. However, just as every free monad, it can be improved using `Codensity`. We just replace the definition with

```
type DList a = Codensity (Free ((,) a)) ()
```

and `toList` with

```
toList = exec . lowerCodensity
```

Now the same expression is executed instantly, as `Codensity` reorders the operations, just like the original difference lists.

Answer (score 17):

> **TL;DR:**
> `DList` for `(++)` serves the same purpose as `Codensity` for `(>>=)`: re-associating the operators to the right.

> This is beneficial, because for both, `(++)` and `(>>=)`, left associated computations
> (can) exhibit **quadratic** runtime behaviour.

### 1. The full story

The plan is as follows:

- We go step by step through an example for `(++)` and `(>>=)`,
  demonstrating the problem with associativity.
- We use CPS to avoid quadratic complexity with `DList` and
  `Codensity`
- Aftermath and Bonus (Generalize from `(++)` to `(<>)`)

### 2. The problem: quadratic runtime behaviour

#### 2a. List `(++)`

> Keep in mind that while I am using `(++)` as an example, this is
> valid for other functions as well, if they work analogous to `(++)`.

So let's first look at the problem with lists.  The concat operation
for lists is commonly [defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%2B%2B):

```
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

which means that `(++)` will always walk the **first** argument from
start to end.  To see when this is a problem consider the following
two computations:

```
as, bs, cs:: [Int]

rightAssoc :: [Int]
rightAssoc = (as ++ (bs ++ cs))

leftAssoc :: [Int]
leftAssoc = ((as ++ bs) ++ cs)
```

Let's start with `rightAssoc` and walk through the evaluation.

```
as = [1,2]
bs = [3,4]
cs = [5,6]
rightAssoc = ([1,2] ++ ([3,4] ++ [5,6]))
           -- pattern match gives (1:[2]) for first arg
           = 1 : ([2] ++ ([3,4] ++ [5,6]))
           -- pattern match gives (2:[]) for first arg
           = 1 : 2 : ([] ++ ([3,4] ++ [5,6]))
           -- first case of (++)
           = 1 : 2 : ([3,4] ++ [5,6])
           = 1 : 2 : 3 : ([4] ++ [5,6])
           = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : ([] ++ [5,6])
           = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : [5,6]
           = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So we have to walk over `as` and `bs`.

Okay that was not too bad, let's continue to `leftAssoc`:

```
as = [1,2]
bs = [3,4]
cs = [5,6]
leftAssoc = (([1,2] ++ [3,4]) ++ [5,6])
          = ((1 : ([2] ++ [3,4])) ++ [5,6])
          = ((1 : 2 : ([] ++ [3,4])) ++ [5,6])
          = ((1 : 2 : [3,4]) ++ [5,6])
          = ([1,2,3,4] ++ [5,6])
          -- uh oh
          = 1 : ([2,3,4] ++ [5,6])
          = 1 : 2 : ([3,4] ++ [5,6])
          = 1 : 2 : 3 : ([4] ++ [5,6])
          = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : ([] ++ [5,6])
          = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : [5,6]
          = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Uh oh, did you see that we had to walk over `as` **twice**?  Once as
`[1,2]` and then again inside `as ++ bs = [1,2,3,4]`.  With each
further operand that is wrongly associated, the list on the **left**
of `(++)` which we have to traverse completely each time will grow
longer in each step, leading to **quadratic** runtime behaviour.

So as you see above left-associated `(++)` will destroy performance.
Which leads us to:

#### 2b. Free monad `(>>=)`

> Keep in mind that while I am using `Free` as an example, this is
> also the case for other monads, e.g. the instance for `Tree` behaves
> like this, too

First, we use the naive `Free` type:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))
```

Instead of `(++)`, we look at `(>>=)` which is [defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#Free) and use
`(>>=)` in prefix form:

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  return = Pure
  (>>=) (Pure a) f = f a
  (>>=) (Free m) f = Free ((>>= f) <$> m)
```

If you compare this with the definition of `(++)` from `2a` above, you can
see that the definition of `(>>=)` again looks at the **first**
argument.  That raises a first concern, will this perform as bad as in
the `(++)` case when associated wrongly?  Well, let's see, I use
`Identity` here for simplicity but the choice of the functor is not
the important fact here:

```
-- specialized to 'Free'
liftF :: Functor f => f a -> Free f a
liftF fa = Free (Pure <$> fa)

x :: Free Identity Int
x = liftF (Identity 20) = Free (Identity (Pure 20))

f :: Int -> Free Identity Int
f x = liftF (Identity (x+1)) = Free (Identity (Pure (x+1)))

g :: Int -> Free Identity Int
g x = liftF (Identity (x*2)) = Free (Identity (Pure (x*2)))

rightAssoc :: Free Identity Int
rightAssoc = (x >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))

leftAssoc :: Free Identity Int
leftAssoc = ((x >>= f) >>= g)
```

We again start with the `rightAssoc` variant first:

```
rightAssoc = (x >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))
                    ~~~
           -- definition of x
           = ((Free (Identity (Pure 20))) >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           -- second case of definition for 'Free's (>>=)
           = Free ((>>= \x -> (f x >>= g)) <$> Identity (Pure 20))
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           -- (<$>) for Identity
           = Free (Identity ((Pure 20) >>= \x -> (f x >>= g)))
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           -- first case of the definition for 'Free's (>>=)
           = Free (Identity (f 20 >>= g))
                             ~~~~
           = Free (Identity ((Free (Identity (Pure 21))) >>= g))
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           -- second case of definition for 'Free's (>>=)
           = Free (Identity (Free ((>>= g) <$> Identity (Pure 21))))
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = Free (Identity (Free (Identity ((Pure 21) >>= g))))
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = Free (Identity (Free (Identity (g 21))))
                                             ~~~~
           = Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Pure 42))))))
```

Puh, okay I added `~~~~` under the expression that is reduced in the
next step for clarity.  If you squint hard enough, you may see some
familiarity from `2a`'s' case for `rightAssoc`: we walk the two first
arguments (now `x` and `f` instead of `as` and `bs`) arguments once.
Without wasting further time, here is `leftAssoc`:

```
leftAssoc = ((x >>= f) >>= g)
             ~~~
          = ((Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>= f) >>= g)
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = (Free ((>>= f) <$> Identity (Pure 20)) >>= g)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = (Free (Identity ((Pure 20) >>= f)) >>= g)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = (Free (Identity (f 20)) >>= g)
                             ~~~~
          = (Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Pure 21)))) >>= g)
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = Free ((>>= g) <$> (Identity (Free (Identity (Pure 21)))))
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          -- uh oh
          = Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Pure 21)) >>= g))
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = Free (Identity (Free ((>>= g) <$> Identity (Pure 21))))
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = Free (Identity (Free (Identity ((Pure 21) >>= g))))
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = Free (Identity (Free (Identity (g 21))))
                                            ~~~~
          = Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Free (Identity (Pure 42))))))
```

If you look close, after the `uh oh` we have to tear down the
intermediate structure again, just like in the `(++)` case (also
marked with `uh oh`).

#### 2c. Result so far

In both cases, `leftAssoc` leads to quadratic runtime behaviour,
because we rebuild the **first** argument several times and tear it
down right again for the next operation.  This means that at each step
in the evaluation we have to *build* and *tear down* a growing
intermediate structure --- bad.

### 3.  The relation between `DList` and `Codensity`

This is where we will discover the relation between `DList` and
`Codensity`.  Each one solves the problem of wrongly associated
computations seen above by using CPS to effectively re-associate to the
right.

#### 3a.  DList

First we introduce the [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.7.1.1/docs/src/Data-DList.html#DList) of `DList` and `append`:

```
newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }

append :: DList a -> DList a -> DList a
append xs ys = DL (unDL xs . unDL ys)

fromList :: [a] -> DList a
fromList = DL . (++)

toList :: DList a -> [a]
toList = ($[]) . unDL
```

and now our old friends:

```
as,bs,cs :: DList Int
as = fromList [1,2] = DL ([1,2] ++)
bs = fromList [3,4] = DL ([3,4] ++)
cs = fromList [5,6] = DL ([5,6] ++)

rightAssoc :: [Int]
rightAssoc = toList $ as `append` (bs `append` cs)

leftAssoc :: [Int]
leftAssoc = toList $ ((as `append` bs) `append` cs)
```

Evaluation is roughly as follows:

```
rightAssoc = toList $ (DL ([1,2] ++)) `append` (bs `append` cs)
           = toList $ DL $ unDL (DL ([1,2] ++)) . unDL (bs `append` cs)
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL (bs `append` cs)
                                              ~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL ((DL ([3,4] ++)) `append` cs)
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL (DL $ unDL (DL ([3,4] ++)) . unDL cs)
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL (DL $ ([3,4] ++) . unDL cs)
                                                                     ~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL (DL $ ([3,4] ++) . unDL (DL ([5,6] ++)))
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . unDL (DL $ ([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++))
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = toList $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . (([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++))
             ~~~~~~
           -- definition of toList
           = ($[]) . unDL $ DL $ ([1,2] ++) . (([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++))
                     ~~~~~~~~~
           -- unDL . DL == id
           = ($[]) $ (([1,2] ++) . (([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++)))
           -- move ($[]) to end
           = (([1,2] ++) . (([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++))) []
           -- def: (.) g f x = g (f x)
           = (([1,2] ++) ((([3,4] ++) . ([5,6] ++)) []))
           = (([1,2] ++) (([3,4] ++) (([5,6] ++) [])))
           -- drop unnecessary parens
           = (([1,2] ++) (([3,4] ++) ([5,6] ++ [])))
           = ([1,2] ++ ([3,4] ++ ([5,6] ++ [])))
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
           -- (xs ++ []) == xs
           = ([1,2] ++ ([3,4] ++ ([5,6])))
           = (as ++ (bs ++ cs))
```

Hah! The result is exactly the same as `rightAssoc` from `2a`.
All right, with tension building up, we move on to `leftAssoc`:

```
leftAssoc = toList $ ((as `append` bs) `append` cs)
          = toList $ (((DL ([1,2]++)) `append` bs) `append` cs)
          = toList $ ((DL (unDL (DL ([1,2]++)) . unDL bs)) `append` cs)
          = toList $ ((DL (unDL (DL ([1,2]++)) . unDL (DL ([3,4]++)))) `append` cs)
          = toList $ ((DL (([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++))) `append` cs)
          = toList $ (DL (unDL (DL (([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++))) . unDL cs))
          = toList $ (DL (unDL (DL (([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++))) . unDL (DL ([5,6]++))))
          = toList $ (DL ((([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++)) . ([5,6]++)))
          = ($[]) . unDL $ (DL ((([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++)) . ([5,6]++)))
          = ($[]) ((([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++)) . ([5,6]++))
          = ((([1,2]++) . ([3,4]++)) . ([5,6]++)) []
          -- expand (f . g) to \x -> f (g x)
          = ((\x -> ([1,2]++) (([3,4]++) x)) . ([5,6]++)) []
          = ((\x -> ([1,2]++) (([3,4]++) x)) (([5,6]++) []))
          -- apply lambda
          = ((([1,2]++) (([3,4]++) (([5,6]++) []))))
          = ([1,2] ++ ([3,4] ++ [5,6]))
          = as',bs',cs' ~ versions of 2a with no prime
          = (as' ++ (bs' ++ cs'))
```

Eureka!  The result is associated correctly (to the right), **no**
quadratic slowdown.

#### 3b. Codensity

Okay if you've come to this point you must be seriously interested, that's good,
because so am I :).  We start with the definition and `Monad` instance of Codensity (with abbreviated names):

```
newtype Codensity m a = C { run :: forall b. (a -> m b) -> m b }

instance Monad (Codensity f) where
  return x = C (\k -> k x)
  m >>= k = C (\c -> run m (\a -> run (k a) c))

-- hidden as a instance for `MonadTrans`
liftCodensity :: Monad m => m a -> Codensity m a
liftCodensity m = C (m >>=)

lowerCodensity :: Monad m => Codensity m a -> m a
lowerCodensity a = run a return
```

I guess you know what comes next:

```
x :: Codensity (Free Identity) Int
x = liftCodensity (Free (Identity (Pure 20)))
  = C (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=)
  -- note the similarity to (DL (as ++))
  -- with DL ~ Codensity and (++) ~ (>>=) !

f :: Int -> Codensity (Free Identity) Int
f x = liftCodensity (Free (Identity (Pure (x+1))))
    = C (Free (Identity (Pure (x+1))) >>=)

g :: Int -> Codensity (Free Identity) Int
g x = liftCodensity (Free (Identity (Pure (x*2))))
    = C (Free (Identity (Pure (x*2))) >>=)

rightAssoc :: Free Identity Int
rightAssoc = lowerCodensity (x >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))

leftAssoc :: Free Identity Int
leftAssoc = lowerCodensity ((x >>= f) >>= g)
```

Before we go through the evaluation once again, you might be
interested in the comparison of `append` from `DList` and `(>>=)` from
`Codensity` (`unDL` `~` `run`), go ahead and do that if you
want, I'll wait for you.

Okay we start with `rightAssoc`:

```
rightAssoc = lowerCodensity (x >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))
                            ~~~
           -- def of x
           = lowerCodensity ((C (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=)) >>= \x -> (f x >>= g))
           -- (>>=) of codensity
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=)) (\a -> run ((\x -> (f x >>= g)) a) c)))
           -- run . C == id
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (f x >>= g)) a) c))
           -- substitute x' for 'Free (Identity (Pure 20))' (same as only x from 2b)
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (f x >>= g)) a) c))
                                                                ~~~
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (Free (Identity (Pure (x+1))) >>=)) >>= g) a) c))
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure (x+1))) >>=)) (\a2 -> run (g a2) c2)))) a) c))
                                                                           ~~~~~~
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (Free (Identity (Pure (x+1))) >>=) (\a2 -> run (g a2) c2)))) a) c))
           -- again, substitute f' for '\x -> Free (Identity (Pure (x+1)))' (same as only f from 2b)
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> run (g a2) c2)))) a) c))
                                                                                                   ~~~~
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure (a2*2))) >>=)) c2)))) a) c))
                                                                                              ~~~~~~
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> (Free (Identity (Pure (a2*2))) >>=) c2)))) a) c))
           -- one last time, substitute g' (g from 2b)
           = lowerCodensity (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)))) a) c))
           -- def of lowerCodensity
           = run (C (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)))) a) c)) return
           = (\c -> x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)))) a) c) return
           = (x' >>= \a -> run ((\x -> (C (\c2 -> (f' x >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)))) a) return)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = (x' >>= \a -> run (C (\c2 -> (f' a >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2))) return)
                           ~~~~~~
           = (x' >>= \a -> (\c2 -> (f' a >>=) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)) return)
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           = (x' >>= \a -> (f' a >>=) (\a2 -> g' a2 >>= return))
           -- m >>= return ~ m
           = (x' >>= \a -> (f' a >>=) (\a2 -> g' a2))
           -- m >>= (\x -> f x) ~ m >>= f
           = (x' >>= \a -> (f' a >>= g'))
           -- rename a to x
           = (x' >>= \x -> (f' x >>= g'))
```

And we can now see that the `(>>=)`s are associated to the right, this
is not yet particularly astonishing, given that this was also the case
at the start.  So, full of anticipation, we turn our attention to our
last and final evaluation trace, `leftAssoc`:

```
leftAssoc = lowerCodensity ((x >>= f) >>= g)
          -- def of x
          = lowerCodensity ((C (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=) >>= f) >>= g)
          -- (>>=) from Codensity
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=)) (\a -> run (f a) c))) >>= g)
                                      ~~~~~~
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> (Free (Identity (Pure 20)) >>=) (\a -> run (f a) c))) >>= g)
          -- subst x'
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> run (f a) c))) >>= g)
          -- def of f
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure (a+1))) >>=)) c))) >>= g)
                                                      ~~~~~~
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (Free (Identity (Pure (a+1))) >>=) c))) >>= g)
          -- subst f'
          = lowerCodensity ((C (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c))) >>= g)
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          = lowerCodensity (C (\c2 -> run (C (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c))) (\a2 -> run (g a2) c2)))
                                      ~~~~~~
          = lowerCodensity (C (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> run (g a2) c2)))
          -- def of g
          = lowerCodensity (C (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> run (C (Free (Identity (Pure (a2*2))) >>=)) c2)))
                                                                                    ~~~~~~
          = lowerCodensity (C (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> (Free (Identity (Pure (a2*2))) >>=) c2)))
          -- subst g'
          = lowerCodensity (C (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)))
          -- def lowerCodensity
          = run (C (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2))) return
          = (\c2 -> (\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> (g' a2 >>=) c2)) return
          = ((\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> g' a2 >>= return))
          = ((\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) (\a2 -> g' a2))
          = ((\c -> (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) c)) g')
          = (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>=) g')
          = (x' >>=) (\a -> (f' a >>= g')
          = (x' >>= (\a -> (f' a >>= g'))
          = (x' >>= (\x -> (f' x >>= g'))
```

**Finally** there we have it, all binds associated to the right, just
how we like them!

### 4. Aftermath

If you made it until here, congratulations.  Let's summarize what we
did:

1. We demonstrated the problem with wrongly associated `(++)` in `2a`
   and `(>>=)` in `2b`
2. We've shown the solution using `DList` in `3a` and `Codensity` in
   `3b`.
3. Demonstrated the power of equational reasoning in Haskell :)

### 5. Bonus

Actually, we can generalize `DList` from `(++)` and use `(<>)` instead
to get `DMonoid`, reordering `(<>)`.

```
newtype DMonoid m = DM { unDM :: m -> m }

instance Monoid m => Monoid (DMonoid m) where
  mempty = DM (mempty <>)
  x `mappend` y = DM (unDM x . unDM y)

liftDM :: Monoid m => m -> DMonoid m
liftDM = DM . (<>)

lowerDM :: Monoid m => DMonoid m -> m
lowerDM = ($ mempty) . unDM
```

Then the comparison goes as follows:

- `DMonoid` is a (my invention) "**monoid** transformer", re-associating `(<>)` to the right
- `Codensity` is a monad transformer, re-associating `(>>=)` to the right

Comment: While the first answer is more on point concerning my question, this certainly deserves an upvote :) Thanks, for the writeup!

Comment: I didn't even plan to write that much, but I just couldn't stop after starting :P